# Unclassifiable statement in an equation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

So far my code is working properly except I am now getting a compiler error error like this:

```
std =std +((x(I) -xbar))**2)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Here is my code:

```
program cardata
implicit none
real, dimension(291) :: x
intEGER I,N
double precision date, odometer, fuel
real :: std=0
real :: xbar=0



  open(unit=10, file="car.dat", FOrm="FORMATTED", STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ")
  read(10,*) N
  do I=1,N

  read(10,*) x(I)
  xbar= xbar +x(I)

  enddo
  xbar = xbar/N
  DO I =1,N
std =std +((x(I) -xbar))**2
  enddo
  std = SQRT((std / (N - 1)))

  print*,'mean:',xbar
  print*, 'std deviation:',std
  close(unit=10)
  end program cardata
```

I am fairly new to this, any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your () aren't balanced.

Comment: Well thanks!! that compiled without errors! but now nothing is being printed, so I don't know if I should write another question as to why my code is not doing the operations it should. However, can I ask for your opinion? Is my code look right? there is 3 columns in the files and I want to average each column and take the std.

Answer (score 2):

Count the parentheses.

```
std =std +((x(I) -xbar))**2)
```

There are three of these: (

There are four of these: )

Comment: UPDATE: I've been able to fix the parenthesis error. However, Is my code look right? there is 3 columns in the file i'm reading and I want to average each column and take the std.The code compiles now, but nothing is being printed.

Comment: Sorry, but my knowledge of FORTRAN dates back to more than 30 years ago. I'm not going to try to debug your code just by looking at it. I will say that if it is printing nothing at all, no error message and not the words 'mean:' and 'std deviation:', then my best guess is that it's never getting out of one of you loops, so that's where I'd focus my attention if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is likely a course I will help you how to debug.
Basically start with some write statements... Check your answers...

```
program cardata
implicit none

...
read(10,*) N
WRITE(*,*)' I read N as ',N

WRITE(*,*)'XBar starts as ', Xbar
do I=1,N
...
! was XBAr ever set to start at 0!
xbar= xbar +x(I)
... 

WRITE(*,*)'Syd starts as ',Std
DO I =1,N
  std =std +((x(I) -xbar))**2
enddo
WRITE(*,*)'Std starts is now ',Std,' and n =',N
! What do we do if N=1 or is Std is negative?
WRITE(*,*)'SQRT(Std)=', SQRT(Std)
std = SQRT((std / (N - 1)))
...
```

At some point You will determine that X is a column, and it is the first column. What is the second column? Y?

Comment: How is it connected with the question about the error message? I mean, you can just say that the parentheses are unbalanced in a sentence and then you can add whatever you want and no-one can complain. I will also not complain at all. One sentence is enough. **But you really should first answer the original question.**

Comment: It is because this is not a discussion forum where you can give any well-meant advice, but it is primarily 1. a question -> 2. answer to the question. And then you can add your advice, no problem at all.

Comment: @VladimirF Question about the error message? The last question was why the results were zero and why only 1 column... Let him see the value of nand then we will know if the answer has value... The question of "what is wrong with my code" in some cases has multiple answers. For the student the answer may be that they need some method To find the problems. His last question from yesterday was about the columns. Maybe he needs the question out of the comments?

Comment: It is just one sentence. "You are missing one parenthesis and that's why it prints the error message you ask about." I really wasn't asking for anything more. Note that if a queation allows many different answers it can be closed as too broad. The point of StackOverflow is that it is simply question -> answer. And one (only one) gets accepted by the asker. Not a discussion about various aspects.

Comment: I think the fact that this question is about the `Unclassifiable statement` message is quite clear.